# Removing matching elements of a TreeSet

Tags: java, set

I am trying to remove all numbers that is divisible with some index in a TreeSet and I am using the following code

```
    TreeSet<Integer> primes = new TreeSet();
    Iterator<Integer> iter = primes.iterator();

    int n = 100;            
    for (int i = n; i > 1; i--){
        primes.add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i ++){
        while (iter.hasNext()){
            int next = iter.next();
            if (next % i == 0){
                primes.remove(next);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(primes);
```

But for some reason, no elements in the set gets removed

Comment: Suggestion: ".", ":", "?" and "," are absolute valid characters also in english, not only in java. :-)

Comment: You should be using a BitSet instead of a TreeSet.  A TreeSet uses about 500x as much memory and is much slower even for a trivial example like this.

Answer (score 2):

First create the `Iterator` after you added the primes and then use `Iterator.remove()` to not get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
TreeSet<Integer> primes = new TreeSet();

    int n = 100;
    for (int i = n; i > 1; i--) {
        primes.add(i);
    }
    Iterator<Integer> iter = primes.iterator();

    for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            int next = iter.next();
            if (next % i == 0) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(primes);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Iterator.remove()` is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration. Use `iter.remove();`

```
  while (iter.hasNext()){
        int next = iter.next();
        if (next % i == 0){
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next. The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method. From [ITERATOR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `iter.remove()` otherwise you'll get `ConcurrentModificationException`s.

In your code you are using `primes.remove(next);`

Change it to `iter.remove()` which will remove the current `next` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
TreeSet<Integer> primes = new TreeSet();

int n = 100;
for (int i = n; i > 1; i--){
    primes.add(i);
}

Iterator<Integer> iter = primes.iterator();

for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i ++){
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        int next = iter.next();
        if (next % i == 0){
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(primes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should end up with concurrent modification exception. You are iterating a treeset using an iterator but at the same time using a remove on the treeset. Please use `iter.remove()` to remove the element from treeset.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your iterator after adding the elements to the set, and remove from the Iterator to avoid ConcurrentModificationException:

```
    TreeSet<Integer> primes = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    int n = 100;
    for (int i = n; i > 1; i--) {
        primes.add(i);
    }

    Iterator<Integer> iter = primes.iterator();

    for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            int next = iter.next();
            if (next % i == 0) {
                // primes.remove(next); // concurrent modification exception!
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(primes);
```